# Runtime error in seekbar android

Tags: android, performance, runtime-error, textview, seekbar

I have created seek bar & I want to update the seek bar value in textview.
I have done following thing.

part of layout file is,

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.15" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >



                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.90" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/seekvalue"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:text=" " />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/showvalue"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" />
```

the java code is,

```
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekvalue);
            // slide_me.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.right_menu);

            slider=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.showvalue);
            slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
               // int progressChanged = 0;

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                   // progressChanged = progress;
                    text.setText(progress);
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

I have got following run time error

```
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.waitress.Calculator$1.onProgressChanged(Calculator.java:39)
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
09-29 08:08:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:506)
```

so please help me...
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `progress` is an `Integer`, so `TextView` will understand it as 'resource id`. To resolve this problem:

```
text.setText("" +progress);
```